# Deploy an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Application to Azure from Command Line

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project which I am trying to publish to Azure from the command line so I tried:

```
dotnet publish MVCApp.csproj /p:PublishProfile=MVCApp.PublishSettings
```

MVCApp.PublishSettings is a Publish Profile I downloaded from Azure.

I run this command and the application is built but not deployed.

I do not get any error so I have no idea why it is not deployed.

Any idea?

Comment: same question here, how to publish to azure from command line. Did you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's .NET Core 2 but still might be useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-cli?tabs=windows